# GROUP BY starting at a specific datetime?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to group results from an observations table.
My table contains stock values every few seconds.
I want to be able to display aggregate information about stocks every 2hrs, 4hrs 8hrs and so forth, but I need these periods to start at 5pm.
For example, if the data starts at 2012-05-23 17:45:34, the first observation will go from 17:00:00 on the 23rd, until 19:00:00 on the 23rd, and so forth.
I'm able to group my data based on the time intervals, but I don't know how to set the start at 5pm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add a condition in the `where` clause. Take the time (from your datetime) and check to make sure it is greater than 17:00:00. If it is before 5pm then don't use it in your calculations.

**EDIT** You mentioned that you already have the grouping done. How about to start at 5pm on the last day you add a subquery in your where clause (not sure the syntax):

```
where datetimeCol >= (select min(date(datetimeCol) + time(5pm)) from tableUsed where previousUsedConditions or id = outerTable.Id)
```

**EDIT**

I know you have a more complicated grouping but (in tsql) this is what I had in mind by using the where statement.

```
declare @tempTable table (mydate smalldatetime)
insert into @tempTable 
    values('2012-05-23 04:37:04.900'),
        ('2012-05-23 18:37:04.900'),
        ('2012-05-24 04:37:04.900'),
        ('2012-05-25 05:37:04.900')     

select * 
from @tempTable as tbl
group by mydate 

select (cast(cast((select min(temp.myDate) from @tempTable as temp) as DATE) as datetime) + cast(cast( '17:00:00.0000000' as time)as datetime))  as 'This is the time that is getting filtered by below'

select * 
from @tempTable as tbl
where tbl.mydate > (cast(cast((select min(temp.myDate) from @tempTable as temp) as DATE) as datetime) + cast(cast( '17:00:00.0000000' as time)as datetime))
```

This gives the following results:

```
(4 row(s) affected)
mydate
-----------------------
2012-05-23 04:37:00
2012-05-23 18:37:00
2012-05-24 04:37:00
2012-05-25 05:37:00

(4 row(s) affected)

This is the time that is getting filtered by below
--------------------------------------------------
2012-05-23 17:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

mydate
-----------------------
2012-05-23 18:37:00
2012-05-24 04:37:00
2012-05-25 05:37:00

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i have observations over a period of many days. i need the result time stamps to start at 5pm on the day of the earliest observation, and i need it to go on every 2 hours since then...

Comment: still i dont at all see how this answers my question.. if i have observations over a periods of a year, and I want to group the observations by a 2 hour periods starting at 5pm on the first day of the observation, how does setting a where clause solve my problem?